# Identifying parents of Clayton Earl Cook who was born 1800 in Virginia, USA?

Tags: 1800s-decade, virginia, 1820s, 1810s

Clayton Cook was born on 4 Jul 1800 in Wythe, Virginia and died on 18 Jul 1863 in Wytheville, Wythe, Virginia during the battle of Wytheville. In the 1830 Census, he was living in Evesham, Wythe, Virginia so his parents might have been living there too.

How can I identify them?

Link to profile: https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Cook-6256

---

His birth date comes from: "Find A Grave Index," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVLL-DDGW : 13 December 2015), Clayton E. Cook, 1863; Burial, Wytheville, Wythe, Virginia, United States of America, East End Cemetery; citing record ID 98996114, Find a Grave, http://www.findagrave.com.

This newspaper states he was a native of Wytheville :https://newspaperarchive.com/pulaski-southwest-times-mar-29-1912-p-1/?tag=clayton+e+cook&rtserp=tags/clayton-e-cook?psi=100&pci=7/

I have not been able to locate an obituary for him.

Comment: What is the source of the information that he "was born on 4 Jul 1800 in Wythe, Virginia"?  Was it perhaps: ""Find A Grave Index," database, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QVLL-DDGW : 13 December 2015), Clayton E. Cook, 1863; Burial, Wytheville, Wythe, Virginia, United States of America, East End Cemetery; citing record ID 98996114, Find a Grave, http://www.findagrave.com."

Comment: Yes that is him

Comment: Have you found an obituary for him?

Comment: No, but this newspaper states he was a native of Wytheville :https://newspaperarchive.com/pulaski-southwest-times-mar-29-1912-p-1/?tag=clayton+e+cook&rtserp=tags/clayton-e-cook?psi=100&pci=7/

Comment: This tree states his father was George Cook Sr. :https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/2:2:3Q3X-L13

Comment: That tree also suggests that his father was aged 55 when Clayton was born.  That's not impossible but I think you should try to find sources to validate it because to me, unless you find that George has a wife about 10 years younger than him (also not impossible), that seems unlikely.